# How does Stack Exchange get their database statistics?

Tags: discussion, database

I was watching ["The Architecture of StackOverflow"](https://youtu.be/t6kM2EM6so4?t=2380) by Marco Cecconi (Stack Exchange developer), and came across this statistics/performance slide:

> [image]

How was the "Performance" table data queried?

Comment: I realize this is a question about a talk by one of our developers about Stack Overflow's architecture, but it sounds like Stack Overflow itself might be a better spot for it. List what you expect to see for your data, what you see instead, and I'm sure someone well-versed in SQL can help you out.

Comment: Well, it's valid to ask how SE are doing things. Can't promise you'll get an answer, but legit to ask. (Just don't ask for help with your specific query, that's off topic here indeed - like Adam said, better fit on SO itself.)

Comment: https://github.com/opserver/Opserver/blob/master/Opserver.Core/Data/SQL/SQLInstance.PerfCounters.cs

Comment: @balpha if it's open source, why not opening https://status.stackexchange.com for everyone as well? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - the platform is open source. Having our monitoring open for everyone? Very different thing.

Comment: Fair point @Oded. Anyway, don't you think it's better to reopen and post that as answer, with the relevant SQL code?